# Passing Excel Services (PowerPivot) Querystring Paramaters to select slicers or simulate slicers

Tags: powerpivot

is it possible to select slicers in PowerPivot 2010 from querystring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bill, its certainly possible to pass a 'variable' to a PowerPivot pivot on sharepoint using a QueryString Webpart.

The technique is documented [here](http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2012/05/drill-across-in-powerpivot-live-demo/#more-4343) - there's a link at the bottom of the post that goes to some VERY detailed PDF instructions.

The trick is that your Pivot needs a report filter for the field as well as slicer - the cell that your report filter value sits in needs to be a named range and the variable is then passed as that name. You can then hide the report filter if necessary - the Slicer and report filters are basically inter-changeable.

Hope this helps. Jacob

Comment: Note: the link to the pdf has been removed:  "I am no longer working at Pivotstream and do not endorse their services.  All links are removed from this article but feel free to look them up if you are interested."